# STL container leak

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, stl

I'm using a vector container to hold instances of an object which contain 3 ints and 2 `std::string`s, this is created on the stack and populated from a function in another class but running the app through deleaker shows that the `std::string`s from the object are all leaked. Here's the code:

```
// Populator function:
void PopulatorClass::populate(std::vector<MyClass>& list) {
    // m_MainList contains a list of pointers to the master objects
    for( std::vector<MyClass*>::iterator it = m_MainList.begin(); it != m_MainList.end(); it++ ) {
        list.push_back(**it);
    }
}

// Class definition
class MyClass {
private:
    std::string m_Name;
    std::string m_Description;
    int m_nType;
    int m_nCategory;
    int m_nSubCategory;
};

// Code causing the problem:
std::vector<MyClass> list;
PopulatorClass.populate(list);
```

When this is run through deleaker the leaked memory is in the allocator for the `std::string` classes.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 (CRT).

Is there anything special I need to do to make the `string`s delete properly when unwinding the stack and deleting the `vector`?

Thanks,
J

Comment: What C++ system are you using?  Visual C++?  Looks to me like your `std::string` implementation is bad, you're doing something odd when initializing or assigning values to the strings, or deleaker is lying to you.

Comment: Just this snippet doesn't have any leaks in it. Can you post populate()?

Comment: 1. Tell us what's your STL implementation and compiler
2. provide PopulatorClass::populate() or a simplified example reproducing the problem.
3. Check your leak detector documentation (and provide the soft name)

Comment: Normally you don't need to do anything special. Some implementations of std::string use reference counting... maybe you have other duplicates of the strings somewhere else?

Comment: Uh, from your code I deduce that the third line in `foo::bar()`, called from the fourth line of `PopulatorClass::populate()` is the culprit. (This code doesn't even compile. Please show the exact code, preferably less than 30LoC. As it is, anything is possible.)

Comment: Edited to contain populator function and compiler details. I'll try to make a simplified version.

Comment: I agree with David.  I've never used deleaker, but I've used similar leak-finding tools.  They're not foolproof, and in particular, Purify reported a great many false positives.  So I suspect deleaker is simply wrong.

Comment: I thought that may be the case and I can see plenty of other stuff which is a false positive (mostly statics) but this function is called often and the commit charge increases hugely when it's running so I suspect the leak is real.

Comment: @JWood: This still isn't a repro we can paste into our editors and try ourselves. Look at Klaim's answer for what you need to provide.

Comment: Since you are using a container of pointers, sure you are not leaking those?

Comment: The pointers are deleted in the destructor of PopulatorClass but the leak is apparently in the `std::string` allocator when adding the classes to the container. I'm going to make a complete compilable example of the problem and edit the post soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Every time you got a problem with the STL implementation doing something strange or wrong like a memory leak, try this** :

- **Reproduce the most basic example of what you try to achieve.** If it runs without a leak, then the problem is in the way you fill the data. **It's the most probable source of problem (I mean your own code).**

Not tested simple on-the-fly example for your specific problem :

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>


// Class definition
struct MyClass  { // struct for convenience
    std::string m_Name;
    std::string m_Description;
    int m_nType;
    int m_nCategory;
    int m_nSubCategory;
};


// Prototype of populator function:
void populate(std::vector<MyClass>& list)
{
    const int MAX_TYPE_IDX = 4;
    const int MAX_CATEGORY_IDX = 8;
    const int MAX_SUB_CATEGORY_IDX = 6;

    for( int type_idx = 0; type_idx < MAX_TYPE_IDX ; ++type_idx)
        for( int category_idx = 0; category_idx < MAX_CATEGORY_IDX ; ++category_idx)
             for( int sub_category_idx = 0; sub_category_idx < MAX_SUB_CATEGORY_IDX ; ++sub_category_idx)
             {
                   std::stringstream name_stream;
                   name_stream << "object_" << type_idx << "_" << category_idx << "_" << sub_category_idx ;
                   std::stringstream desc_stream;
                   desc_stream << "This is an object of the type N°" << type_idx << ".\n";
                   desc_stream << "It is of category N°" << category_idx << ",\n";
                   desc_stream << "and of sub-category N°" << category_idx << "!\n";

                   MyClass object;
                   object.m_Name = name_stream.str();
                   object.m_Description = desc_stream.str();
                   object.m_nType = type_idx;
                   m_nCategory = 
                   m_nSubCategory = 
                   list.push_back( object );
             }
}


int main()
{
    // Code causing the problem:
    std::vector<MyClass> list;
    populate(list);

    // memory leak check?
    return 0;
 }
```

- If you still got the memory leak, **first check that it's not a false-positive from your leak detection software**.
- Then if it's not, **google for memory leak problems with your STL implementation** (most of the time on the compiler developer website). The implementor might provide a bug tracking tool where you could search in for the same problem and potential solution.
- If you still can't find the source of the leak, maybe **try to build your project with a different compiler (if you can)** and see if it have the same effect. Again if the leak still occurs, the problem have a lot of chances to come from your code.

Comment: Thanks for the code, I've used it to write a small example and it does not report any leaks. I'm going to go over the trace in more detail to see what's different as I am convinced there is a leak from the memory usage of the app. I'll post back with what I find.

Comment: Cool! Maybe it's the STL leak pointed by Alexey that is used somewhere else and do the leak. Then when you get back to the function the leak already happened in non obvious code.

Comment: After a great deal more debugging and trying to reproduce the problem in a test app, it seems that it is the actual object that's leaking and not the memory allocated by the string class. I have yet to figure out exactly how and where it's leaking but I have ruled out the container and the string class. It's definitely a bug in my code.

Comment: Still check the comment I made in Alexey's post about std::string allocator not playing correctly with move semantic in VS2010 STL implementation - if you don't find the leak source in your code. You could try VS2010 SP1 Beta that have a fix, see if it solve your problem.

Answer (score 6):

May be [Memory leak with `std::vector<std::string>`](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/596565/memory-leak-with-std-vector-std-string-insert-using-const-std-string#details) or something like this.

Comment: +1 Certainly the source of the problem. That said, what is strange is that the bug seem to be with std::vector< std::string >, it don't point the same problem with std::vector< my_struct_having_string_members > ...

Comment: @JWood: Without the link I would have dismissed this as a JWood problem. With the link I am more accepting to the possibility of a leak. But before I accept that as the answer I would need a compilable example with output that exhibited the leak (the above code is not enough at this point to confirm or deny the existence of a leak).

Comment: Read the comments there : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/12/09/vs2010-sp1-beta-what-s-on-it-for-c-developers.aspx It seems like the leak bug is not dirctly related to std::vector<std::string> but more a move-semantic VS std:string implementation problem. So it might really be the source of your problem. That said, if the example I gave in my answer works without a leak then I suggest (if you can) you try to build your project with VC9/SP1 see if it leaks again. If it don't, then it might really be move semantic problem. Not sure why my example does work then...

Answer (score 0):

Probably same root issue as Alexey's link. The shipped version has broken move code for basic_string. MS abandoned us VC10 users, so you must fix it yourself. in xstring file you have this:

```
_Myt& assign(_Myt&& _Right)
    {        // assign by moving _Right
    if (this == &_Right)
        ;
    else if (get_allocator() != _Right.get_allocator()
        && this->_BUF_SIZE <= _Right._Myres)
        *this = _Right;
    else
        {        // not same, clear this and steal from _Right
        _Tidy(true);
        if (_Right._Myres < this->_BUF_SIZE)
            _Traits::move(this->_Bx._Buf, _Right._Bx._Buf,
                _Right._Mysize + 1);
        else
            {        // copy pointer
            this->_Bx._Ptr = _Right._Bx._Ptr;
            _Right._Bx._Ptr = 0;
            }
        this->_Mysize = _Right._Mysize;
        this->_Myres = _Right._Myres;

        _Right._Mysize = 0;
        _Right._Myres = 0;
        }
    return (*this);
    }
```

Note the last

_Right._Myres = 0;

that should happen only under the last condition, for the short case _Right should better be left alone.

As the capacity is set to 0 instead of 15, other code will take unintended branch in function Grow() when you assign another small string and will allocate a block of memory just to trample over the pointer with the immediate string content.

Comment: It turned out that this bug was fixed in VS2010SP1. Though on my machine I had the old version of files -- despite the SP being installed, and even using 'reapply' did not cure the situation. It got fixed after I asked to remove the SP1 entirely, then applied it again from scratch. Then the 2011 version of sources replaced the 2009 ones correctly.