# c++ memory leak when using std::string in shared memory array

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I have this class

```
class LayoutEntry
{
  unsigned int id_;
  string name_;  
  bool isInput_;
};
```

The copy constructor looks like this:

```
LayoutEntry(const LayoutEntry &other)
        : id_(other.id_),
        name_(other.name_), 
        isInput_(other.isInput_)
    {
    }
```

Objects of this class are put inside a map within another class

```
class DataLayoutDescription 
{
    unsigned int sz_;
    set<LayoutEntry, SortByOffset> impl;

    // HERE!!!
    map<unsigned int, LayoutEntry> mapById;
```

The copy constructor of this class looks like this:

```
DataLayoutDescription::DataLayoutDescription(const DataLayoutDescription &other)
    :sz_(other.sz_), impl(other.impl), mapById(other.mapById)
{   
}
```

Now the question:

- I Get a memory leak for each LayoutEntry when run like printed
- If I remove `mapById(other.mapById)` in the copy constructor of DataLayoutDescription  then there is no memleak
- If I remove `name_(other.name_),` The memory leaks are also gone

Why?

**EDIT**

For Testing I use BOOST::UnitTest at the end I get a memory leak dump

```
C:\wc\05_EAPGit\Debug>EapLibTest.exe --run-test=SharedVectorTest
Running 7 test cases...

*** No errors detected
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{1378} normal block at 0x005815C0, 16 bytes long.
 Data: <                > CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD
{1377} normal block at 0x00581580, 16 bytes long.
 Data: <                > CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD
{1376} normal block at 0x00581540, 16 bytes long.
 Data: <                > CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD
Object dump complete.
```

**Possible Reason?**
I persist the DataLayoutDescription in a shared memory area using this method

```
void DataLayoutDescription::Save(LayoutEntry *les, unsigned int maxEntries) const
{
    int n = std::max(impl.size(), maxEntries);
    int i = 0;
    for (DataLayoutDescription::iterator it = begin(); it != end(); ++it)
    {
        les[i] = *it;  // Source of memory leak here???
        ++i;
    }
}
```

I dereference the iterator ant store a copy of this in the array that is located in the shared memory region. Is there something wrong? The shared memory is deleted on exit.

**Furhter Trackdown**
The class LayoutEntry is placed in an array within a shared memory area and contains a string. The reason for the memory leak is that the string gets resized. Thus it allocates more memory on the heap. Now I guess that this memroy will not be freed since the original memory is located in the shared memory. Could this be the reason? Next thing I will try to remove the string and replace it with an char array of fixed length.

... after several minutes

This was it. After replacing the string with a fixed array of char the memory leak dissapeared. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This looks perfect. What makes you think that there's memory leak here?

Comment: There's no apparent memory leak in the code you posted. Why do you think you've got one?

Comment: @schoetbi: If you run the program twice are allocation numbers in that dump the same?

Comment: @sharptooth: Yes the allocation numbers stay constant if I do not alter the code

Comment: @nos: DataLayoutDescription is on the stack

Comment: I would suggest using the debug version of new (can't format code in comment): #ifdef _DEBUG 
#define BOOST_TEST_DEBUG_NEW new( _CLIENT_BLOCK, __FILE__, __LINE__) 
#define new BOOST_TEST_DEBUG_NEW 
#else 
#define BOOST_TEST_DEBUG_NEW 
#endif 
This will give a fuller output, like: Dumping objects -> 
.....\unit_test_example_01.cpp(33) : {208} client block at 0x003262A0, 
(SORRY for the format)

Comment: @schoetbi: Okay, then since you seem to be using Visual C++ you could use the technique described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154941/what-useful-things-can-i-do-with-visual-c-debug-crt-allocation-hooks-except-fin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the leak was the LayoutEntry class that stores a string. The base object (before modification) was placed in an array within a shared memory area. After altering the string a resize operation was performed, this memory was lost. After replacing the string by an array of chars (fixed length) the memory leak went away. I am happy now but ask myself if the string class does something wrong, or is there a way to put a custom allocator into the std::string? I will not need this because I will go with the char array but I am just curious if something like this would work and weather I am right with this assumtions?

This is the modified class

```
class LayoutEntry
{
  unsigned int id_;
  char name_[128];  
  bool isInput_;
};
```

Thanks everybody for your help! The tips for debugging the memory leak helped me a lot.

Comment: The C++ string allocates more memory to hold the actual string. What you copied into shared memory was just a pointer and length. The actual string was never in the shared memory so when you delete the shared memory you lost the pointer that would have called delete[].

Answer (score 4):

It looks like [the memory leak that was introduced in Visual Studio 2010 C++ standard library, fixed with SP1](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/596565/memory-leak-with-std-vector-std-string-insert-using-const-std-string#details). If it's your compiler (without SP1) that's certainly the problem.

See also those answers : [STL container leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494012/stl-container-leak)

Comment: I acceppted this not because it is the easiest answer for me but the symptoms look like it. I have not done everything you suggested but since I leak also 16 bytes it looks like it. One thing that still bothers me is that I have SP1 installed.

Comment: If you have VS2010 SP1 installed, then follow my accepted answer in the link (didn't even remarked that it was from me...).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that when you say you have a memory leak, you mean some checker like Purify or valgrind is telling you so, the most likely scenario is that somehow you're leaking `LayoutEntry` objects, NOT `string` objects directly. I got bitten by this once and got confused because my own object was getting leaked, but the leak was tagged (by valgrind) to `std::string` which made it harder to find.

Alternately it may just be detecting a growth. Did you try doing a `clear` on your map prior to exiting?

Answer (score 1):

If you have consistent allocation numbers in the leaks, you can set the debug memory allocator to break at that specific allocation using `_CrtSetBreakAlloc`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4wth1ha5.aspx

For example, adding `_CrtSetBreakAlloc(1378)` to your code will cause a debug break when allocating block number 1378. You can then use the debugger to follow the code back to the caller.